# Querying SQL + HDF5 hybrids

Tags: mysql, database, orm, hdf5

I am developing a hybrid SQL (with mySQL) and HDF5 database solution for data analysis. Some of my data fits really well into relational and SQL is quite handy and effective as a query language but then I have big numerical data (arrays and matrices with thousands or elements/rows/columns). So, I keep these in a HDF5 file, and arrange the group hierarchy based on some commonalities among each observation, so that if I add the fields I've used for deriving that hierarchy onto the SQL Select query, and add an index in the relational DB with the position in the dataset of that particular observation, I get all I need to locate the numerical data in the HDF5 file fast.

I'm writing all this in Python, Numpy and h5py. However, at some point I would like to make the whole thing more user friendly and maybe even have it available on a webserver for querying and visualization. My initial guess is to start from an ORM like Django's or SQLAlchemy and then add some of my actual scripts to handle the HDf5. Does anyone have experience with this type of hybrid approach, especially at this level? Any tips for a newbie?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this work:
[Supporting a Light-Weight Data Management Layer over HDF5](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6546110&tag=1)

BTW, more functions including indexing, sampling and structural grouping have been developed after this work.

Comment: I know the paper. But is this software available somewhere?

Comment: It's not open sourced yet, but I can send you the source code if you need.

Comment: Sadly my reputation doesn't permit up votes (yet) but thank you very much for the article it is very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from using retrieve the HDF5 dataset address in the file (with H5Oget_info) and storing that in the database record.  Then, then dataset address can be used with H5Oopen_by_addr() to open the HDF5 dataset directly, without traversing the group hierarchy in the HDF5 file.

See:
http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-GetInfo
and
http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-OpenByAddr